# My cat has seen a dog and started to attack me

Tags: cats, aggression

My cat has seen the neighbor's dog through the window and started screaming, very nervous and scared. Had already happened other times, and I usually close the shutter interrupting the visual contact.

But today suddenly she has started screaming VERY loudly, and when I went to close the blinds she started to attack me, snorting and squealing, very angry. Quietly, and drawing that she was following me to keep attacking, I have managed to lock her in the bathroom, but she was scratching the door unabated and still screaming, as if she was suffering a lot of pain. After it had been quiet a bit, I went to look, but when she saw me she started screaming again, and I realized that she was releasing urine, I guess because of fear.

She has never acted this way. She is an eight years old spayed female, and never in her life has been aggressive and screaming.

What's the best option to deal with that?

Answer (score 2):

You could talk to the vet about anxiety medication.

You could explain the problem to your neighbor, and ask them to use a door on the other side of the house.

You could keep the blinds down on that side of the house at all times.

Comment: Today there are drugs against anxiety which are derived from milk protein which have very few side effects, today.

Comment: @Ariser - Could you share more info about the, please?  Sounds intriguing.

Comment: @aparente001: Name of the drug I know is Zylkène, easy to find in internet. I can order it for an affordable price at many online pharmacies. A daily dose for our 7 kg cat costs 0.9 € max. If I take the big doses for dogs and split it, which is a bit tricky, I pay 0.4 € per day. Smaller cats need considerable less.