# Adopted kitten brought home , what is normal behavior?

Tags: behavior

Recently adopted a 8 month old kitten from a rescue shelter. On the same day bringing her home she lunged and attacked my daughter, hissed and growl at my husband and  I. We left her in the bathroom that evening with toys, nice bed, food and litter. In the evening was meowing a bit and my husband wanted to check on her. He opened the door a little and she immediately lunged and hissed at him. He quickly closed the door and she continued hissing, growl and scratch on the door throughout the night. Is this normal? I’m not sure what to do? It was just the first day and I know animals usually need 2 weeks to adjust to a new home, but my daughter is already fearful of the kitten.

Comment: So you know anything about her life before and in the shelter? Sometimes information like "had have no human contact before" or "reached the shelter with hurts" help to understand the behavior. Maybe she was abused by a human in some way and now she connects humans with pain only.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/27379/12501) describes the same kind of behavior. Your cat is terrified and attacks out of fear. You **must not look her in the eyes** because this is a sign of agression in cats. A mild tranqualizer (ask your vet for recommendations) might help her calm down.